# Time Count Down With Php/MySql And Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

First of all i will try explain what exectly i need (Sorry for my English).

I have Some table in Database with datatime, now i need to do **Time Count Down** .

**Example:** Information from db with php/mysqli

The time in database with this format **2014-08-05 12:30:51**

```
$link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db);
$a = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT time FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$time = strtotime($a['time']) - strtotime(gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()));
```

The $time will be in seconds format.

And now i need Jquery/Ajax help to **Show Time Count Down** and when the time will GET ZERO. Update information + **start the time again** by the new **$time** information output from mysqli query - Without refresh page by myself.

this is information to update

```
$(this).ready(function(){ 
     $.ajax({
        url: 'somthing.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: '',
        success: function(data) {
        $('#table_for_xxx').html(data);
        $('#table').load('update.php');
        return false;
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: `time()` returns a UTC timestamp unconditionally. Why do you take that timestamp, convert to a string, then BACK to a timestamp? total waste of cpu cycles.

Comment: @MarcB I do not care how, the main thing that worked. 
And it was in the previous script.

Comment: well, given your db code is broken, in that you never actually FETCH your result row, `$a['time']` does not exist, and you'll be outputting `null - large_int`.

Comment: @MarcB yes, thx i forgot